# Power BI: Service Principal

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to set up my Service Principal to use for Power BI Embedded paginated reports. As per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers#considerations-and-limitations) I can't use a Master-User set up. (Though I did get Master-User set up originally). It seems to me like I am stuck on [step 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core#step-6---service-principal-api-access) as the Admin Portal they show is different than mine. Microsoft shows Tenant Settings which I don't have.

[image: Admin Portal] This is the picture of what my account shows without the Tenant Settings.

I am running the sample code for an AppOwnsData and my config file (in appsettings.json) is passing their validation service.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// Licensed under the MIT license.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace AppOwnsData.Services
{
    using AppOwnsData.Models;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
    using System;

    public class ConfigValidatorService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates whether all the configuration parameters are set in appsettings.json file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="appSettings">Contains appsettings.json configuration values</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ValidateConfig(IOptions<AzureAd> azureAd, IOptions<PowerBI> powerBI)
        {
            string message = null;
            bool isAuthModeMasterUser = azureAd.Value.AuthenticationMode.Equals("masteruser", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            bool isAuthModeServicePrincipal = azureAd.Value.AuthenticationMode.Equals("serviceprincipal", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.AuthenticationMode))
            {
                message = "Authentication mode is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.AuthorityUrl))
            {
                message = "Authority is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.ClientId))
            {
                message = "Client Id is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (isAuthModeServicePrincipal && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.TenantId))
            {
                message = "Tenant Id is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (azureAd.Value.ScopeBase is null || azureAd.Value.ScopeBase.Length == 0)
            {
                message = "Scope base is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(powerBI.Value.WorkspaceId))
            {
                message = "Workspace Id is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (!IsValidGuid(powerBI.Value.WorkspaceId))
            {
                message = "Please enter a valid guid for Workspace Id in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(powerBI.Value.ReportId))
            {
                message = "Report Id is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (!IsValidGuid(powerBI.Value.ReportId))
            {
                message = "Please enter a valid guid for Report Id in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (isAuthModeMasterUser && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.PbiUsername))
            {
                message = "Master user email is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (isAuthModeMasterUser && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.PbiPassword))
            {
                message = "Master user password is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }
            else if (isAuthModeServicePrincipal && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureAd.Value.ClientSecret))
            {
                message = "Client secret is not set in appsettings.json file";
            }

            return message;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks whether a string is a valid guid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configParam">String value</param>
        /// <returns>Boolean value indicating validity of the guid</returns>
        private static bool IsValidGuid(string configParam)
        {
            Guid result = Guid.Empty;
            return Guid.TryParse(configParam, out result);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get says

> Error Details: Operation returned an invalid status code
> 'Unauthorized'
>
> at
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.GetReportInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(Guid
> groupId, Guid reportId, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GetReportInGroupAsync(IReportsOperations
> operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GetReportInGroup(IReportsOperations
> operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId) at
> AppOwnsData.Services.PbiEmbedService.GetEmbedParams(Guid workspaceId,
> Guid reportId, Guid additionalDatasetId) in
> C:\Users\AA\Downloads\PowerBI-Developer-Samples-master\PowerBI-Developer-Samples-master.NET
> Core\Embed for your
> customers\AppOwnsData\Services\PbiEmbedService.cs:line 46 at
> AppOwnsData.Controllers.EmbedInfoController.GetEmbedInfo() in
> C:\Users\AA\Downloads\PowerBI-Developer-Samples-master\PowerBI-Developer-Samples-master.NET
> Core\Embed for your
> customers\AppOwnsData\Controllers\EmbedInfoController.cs:line 45

I am on a trial but I haven't seen anything that would indicate that this isn't part of the trial. I also looked in other places in my account but couldn't find anything remotely similar.
Any help is appreciated. Please lmk if more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To access Tenant settings in [**PowerBI Admin Portal**](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/tenantSettings) then the user must have **Fabric Administrator/Global Administrator**.

Initially when I tried to login with the user, I got the same issue:

[image]

Hence to resolve the error, I assigned the user **Fabric Administrator role** like below:

[image]

[image]

After assigning the role, I am able to access the tenant settings:

[image]

This will resolve the "**Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized**" error too.

Comment: Is that Add Assignments page in Power BI or Azure? And will it work in the trial version?

Comment: Its in Azure yes it will work in trail version too

Comment: Amazing, Tysm! It looked a bit different in mine and I had to go to the top level account, not the tenant.

Comment: Hi @Rukmini, I am still getting an 'Unauthorized' status code. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are you able to see the tenant settings?

Comment: Yes, and I enabled it.

Comment: Nvmd, I needed to add the app name to the workspace access but I just added the tenant.